# How to find specific row in ng-table by text [protractor]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automated-tests, protractor

I want to select specific element from a table by the second column value (I removed the whitespaces that where rendered), and after that element is found I want to click on it. (the return in true)
I've tried this, but it doesn't click on it, it just finds the element.

The html code for that filed I want to select is the following:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" id="Panel" class="tbl-option-list" template-pagination="directives/controls/Pager/Pager.html">
    <caption translate>Orders</caption>
    <tr id="Panel">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <th class="fixed-width-glyphicon"></th>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <th translate>Identifier</th>
    </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in $data track by $index" ng-class="{'active-bg': order.$selected}" ng-click="changeSelection(order,  getRowActions(order))">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <td class="fixed-width-glyphicon">
            <div class="fixed-width-glyphicon">
                {{item.priority.toUpperCase()[0]}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <td>{{item.identifierCode}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The select command from protractor is:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in $data track by $index')).filter(function(row) {
    row.getText().then(function(txt) {
        txt = txt.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var found = txt.split('ID0001');
        return found.length > 1;
    });
}).click();
```

Protractor is a framework based on Selenium made for angular js automated testing. Even a solution based on Selenium may work...

Comment: Try placing `return` before `row.getText().then(function(txt) { ...`.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the filtered elements before trying to click on them i guess. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in $data track by $index')).filter(function(row) {
    return row.getText().then(function(txt) {
        txt = txt.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var found = txt.split('ID0001');
        return found.length > 1;
    });
}).then(function(elem){
    elem[0].click();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I received the following error after modifying the code: "errorMsg": "TypeError: Object  has no method 'click'",

Comment: I almost forgot, filter function returns an element array finder. So clicking on the first element using array[0] should be performed. Updated the code. Also can you see how many elements are getting returned in the `.then()` function.

Comment: P.S. Cand you tell me how you cand debug Protractor tests?
My IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I am afraid there are no IDE's for protractor specifically. However you can use IDE's for javascript which can help you out with JS syntax and few javascript functions that you will be using in your protractor scripts like WebStorm or Atom or Brackets.