# How to find specific row in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

So this is question is basically to get an elaboration on how the solution mentioned at [[How to find specific row in ng-table by text [protractor]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715162/how-to-find-specific-row-in-ng-table-by-text-protractor]) works.

I am copying the code snippet here

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in $data track by    $index')).filter(function(row) {
    return row.getText().then(function(txt) {
        txt = txt.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var found = txt.split('ID0001');
        return found.length > 1;
    });
}).then(function( elem){
   elem[0].click();
});
```

Here, I am unable to get how it is able to specifically select ID0001 in the then clause. I get the part of using split function, as when nothing is found it will simply return 1 and incase if it’s found the length will be greater than and hence will return true. However, I am confused as to where it returned the element we wanted to find so to perform the click operation on it ?

Answer (score 0):

`element.all().filter()` is used to find out elements satisfied your requirement from the element list returned by `element.all()`.

the result of  `filter()` is an new list which may includes all/partial elements of `element.all()`.

`filter()` requires a function as argument. And require the function should return a boolean/promise.  When the `boolean/<promise<boolean>` is equal to `True`, the iterating element will be added into the returned new list.

Actually, `element.all().filter()` similar as `Array.filter`, you can learn it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to help you understand the former.

Answer (score 0):

If `.split('ID0001')` is successful, the string will be split into at least two parts and `found.length > 1` will be `true`. If `true` is returned, that means you have the element you want so `.then()` click on it.